# Running output of sql query directly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a set of queries to add 4 different columns in different tables with somewhat similar names. So, I made a union of all 4 queries by calling INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS in a set of dynamic sql having names of all tables and for all 4 columns.
Now I want to execute all these queries in one go without executing each query one by one. So how can I achieve it?

This is the query I made:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT
'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''FromDays'') ALTER TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +' ADD FromDays varchar(50) NULL; ' AS qry
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tbl_PPT_Query_Order%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT
'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''ToDays'') ALTER TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +' ADD ToDays varchar(50) NULL; ' AS qry
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tbl_PPT_Query_Order%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT
'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''FromDays_Top'') ALTER TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +' ADD FromDays_Top varchar(50) NULL; ' AS qry
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tbl_PPT_Query_Order%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT
'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''ToDays_Top'') ALTER TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +' ADD ToDays_Top varchar(50) NULL; ' AS qry
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tbl_PPT_Query_Order%') x
```

Which is giving me the output as:
[image: output]

Comment: What is stopping you running them one after another in a batch?

Comment: @iamdave If by batch, you mean copying the output and running directly, then I cant do that, because the names of tables varies in different databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @SQL = (
    (
        SELECT
        'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''MyColumn1'') ALTER TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +' ADD MyColumn1 varchar(50) NULL; ' AS qry
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%myTable%'
    )
    + CHAR(13) +
    (
        SELECT
        'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''MyColumn2'') ALTER TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +' ADD MyColumn2 varchar(50) NULL; ' AS qry
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%myTable%'
    )
    + CHAR(13) +
    (
        SELECT
        'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''MyColumn3'') ALTER TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +' ADD MyColumn3 varchar(50) NULL; ' AS qry
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%myTable%'
    )
)
;
SELECT @SQL
--EXECUTE SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL
;
```

If the result is to your liking, remove the `SELECT @SQL` at the bottom and un-comment the `EXECUTE SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL` to execute the commands.

**First Edit:**

Okay, I apologize for having misunderstood the context of the question.  How about something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(
    (
    SELECT CHAR(10) 
    + 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' 
    + TABLE_NAME 
    + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''FromDays'') ALTER TABLE '
    + TABLE_NAME 
    +' ADD FromDays varchar(50) NULL; '
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tbl_PPT_Query_Order%'
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
,1,4000),'#x0D',CHAR(10))
    +
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(
        (
        SELECT CHAR(10) 
        + 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' 
        + TABLE_NAME 
        + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''ToDays'') ALTER TABLE '
        + TABLE_NAME 
        +' ADD ToDays varchar(50) NULL; '
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
        WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tbl_PPT_Query_Order%'
        ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,1,4000),'#x0D',CHAR(10))
    +
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(
        (
        SELECT CHAR(10) 
        + 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' 
        + TABLE_NAME 
        + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''FromDays_Top'') ALTER TABLE '
        + TABLE_NAME 
        +' ADD FromDays_Top varchar(50) NULL; '
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
        WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tbl_PPT_Query_Order%'
        ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,1,4000),'#x0D',CHAR(10))
    +
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(
        (
        SELECT CHAR(10) 
        + 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' 
        + TABLE_NAME 
        + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''ToDays_Top'') ALTER TABLE '
        + TABLE_NAME 
        +' ADD ToDays_Top varchar(50) NULL; '
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
        WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tbl_PPT_Query_Order%'
        ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,1,4000),'#x0D',CHAR(10))
SELECT @SQL
--EXECUTE SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am getting error in this approach as, "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.". I did not change anything in your query and just changed the names of table and columns.

Comment: How many rows do you get back if you just run `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tbl_PPT_Query_Order%'?`

Comment: Like I said, this varies from db to db, in one DB, I get 4 rows, in another I get 5 rows, thats why I want it dynamically.

Comment: I wish I could double Upvote your answer. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot. Cheers!

Comment: Just happy to help.  Hope it serves you well.